# Android: programmatically change the application label?

Tags: android

It doesn't seem possible, but I was hoping someone may be aware of a way.  Can the label of the application (the one defined in the manifest file by    `android:label="@string/app_name"`) be set from code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is read-only, AFAIK.

If your objective is to change the title bar of your activities, you can call `setTitle()`.

Comment: Possibly there is a way to modify the value of a string resource from code?

Comment: @ab11: That's *definitely* not possible.

Comment: it works... to be more precise, use `getActionBar().setTitle("bla bla bla");`

Comment: @RicardoAppleton: The OP is specifically *not* referring to the action bar, but rather other uses of that string resource.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly use this to change actionBar's text pragmatically in onCreate() method....very easy!

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("yourString");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
this.setTitle("YourString");
```