# Is it possible to change application label by code?

Tags: android

In the manifest, I can set application label like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

But I want to code this, is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use setTitle() to change the label.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: programmatically change the application label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991151/android-programmatically-change-the-application-label)

Comment: In what cases do you want to change the label? You could provide several different strings for the label, if, for example, label should change on screen orientation or language.

Comment: @Stan actually, I have a library project and it holds all strings, and I don't want to keep a string resource file just for app_name in my non-library projects.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: @user1281750 answered above.

Comment: So you would like more java code then having 1 resource file with one entry.. I really don't see the problem here

Comment: @user1281750 I'm already customizing the Application(already coding), it was supposed to be one line in my ApplicationExtended class. Don't you think it's worth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Because Android application package archive is **Read-Only** format.

So you can not change the label of the application. Only you can read application label.

Answer (score 2):

Application's `android:label` refers to a fixed resource .

But the string under this referrer could have multiple values, depending on configuration qualifier names (values-en, -large, -land, etc.), according to [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).