# Change Locale programmatically with ActionBarActivity and SupportActionBar

Tags: android, locale, android-support-library

I have a multi-language app whose `Locale` is changed programmatically.

When the application is first created, it looks into a specific `SharedPreferences` file and set the locale accordingly.

Then the user can go into a specific `Activity P` and choose among the available languages (now only two languages are available).

This is what I do in `P`, with `lang` being a `String`:

```
// set locale to that chosen by the user
((MyApp) getApplication()).setMyAppLocale(lang); 

// get the Locale object
Locale locale = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getMyAppLocale();

// classic code
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

// clear the activity stack and restart the MainActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(MainActivity.PARAM_DO_RESTART, true);
intent.putExtras(extras);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The activity `MainActivity` receives a new `Intent` and does this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent anotherIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(anotherIntent);
    setIntent(anotherIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        if (extras.getBoolean(PARAM_DO_RESTART, false)) {
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_DO_RESTART, false);
            setIntent(intent);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } // if extras != null
```

In this way, `MainActivity`'s onCreate is called again and the resources loaded again in the new `Locale`.

Everything is ok, **but one thing**.

All the strings appear in the correct locale, **but the titles of all the activities stay in the language they were first created** when the app was launched. They did not change. My activities are actually instances of `ActionBarActivity` and the titles are shown in `SupportActionBar`.

Question: how can I force those titles to be changed according to the current `Locale`?

Note: A simple solution is to call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_X));` for every `Activity X`. However, since there are quite a few activities I would rather find a way to have it done automagically.

Note: I am using API Level 19, with support library v7.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991151/android-programmatically-change-the-application-label) the title is read only, so you should specify the title manually and cannot do it automatically. My guess is because it uses resource specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` which cannot be changed dynamically.

Comment: That is the problem, but it is a bug or should be considered so. The title is not read-only. There is a way to do it automatically, I will add the answer as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't find any docs about that, but in my opinion it cannot be done as same as in `manifest` there are other labels, for example `Theme`, cannot be changed unless you call `setTheme()`. I add this question to favorite, I'd like to read the answer if you will find the trick. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way in the answer provided by MiroM to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726377/how-to-force-android-application-to-reload-the-activity-title-corresponding-to-t). Add the following code to your base `Activity` class, wherever it is best suited.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        ActivityInfo ai = pm.getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (ai.labelRes != 0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(ai.labelRes);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.stacktrace();
    }
```

I hope someone else will reach this question and provide a more general way of doing this. This method is really useful when your activities have a common superclass, which was my case, but it is not true  in general.

Comment: good one. also for making it more general I think it is possible to put this method in `BaseActivity.class` extended from `ActionBarActivity` so all other activities extended from `BaseActivity` will have same behavior.